# How to load classes from a jar or a directory

Tags: java, jar, classloader

I have found code to load classes from a directory, and code to load from a jar.  My project needs to do both - use a directory when it is stand alone, and use a jar when it is jarred up for other projects.

Right now I test if the jar exists and use one function, otherwise I use the other.  And while the code is vaguely similar, I can't see how to unify them.

It seems to me there must be some way that works in both cases....

Answer (score 1):

You should NOT do this by hand. Use appropriate classpath depending on where it is running.

Running on stand-alond

```
java -classpath <path-to-folder> <main-class>
```

Elsewhere

```
java -classpath <path-to-jar> <other-main-class>
```

But why can't you use the jar when running stand-alone?

Comment: The project has jars from other projects.  It doesn't have a jar of itself.

Comment: So you are talking about loading some third-party classes? Why can't you always use jar?